# Travelhacks pop up ads

Tags: ads, lagging

I keep getting a Travelhacks pop up ad. Chrome just opens and the travelhacks site pops up then I get a video ad thing in my notification bar. Idk where its coming from or how to stop it from continuing. Does anyone have this problem or know how to stop it. I have an Android( marshmallow) lg stylo 2. Oh and lately my phone has been very slow and lagging a ton this all just started recently. Someone help please!!

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! We've had [several such reports here already](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=pop+up+ads+answers%3A1) which got answered. You might wish to check with them.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you have installed some AdWare on your phone. The best and easiest thing to get rid of that is factory resetting your phone.